# JSP: String to Boolean conversion

Tags: string, jsp, boolean, type-conversion

I get "true" or "false" as **strings** in JSP, but to use it in the rest of the code, I need to convert it to Boolean.

How to do the conversion in the JSP and do I need to include something for the same.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JSP documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaid.html), literal `"true"` will work for boolean test, it will be converted to a type `Boolean.TRUE`, so you don't need to convert it to boolean explicitly. So if your attribute is `'booleanVar'` which contains values `"true"` or `"false"`, just use it directly in boolean test, such as

```
<c:if test="${booleanVar}">
</c:if>
```